# check if a window is open or closed, *.bat and/ or *.vbs

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

Its just a question of shear curiosity, but I was wondering if its possible to check if a window to a given directory ls open or not.

I'm most comfortable with a *.bat solution but my gut instincts tell me its probably more likely to be a *.vbs solution instead.

again just a curiosity question, so I have no sample code to go by as yet...

Comment: There's code to enumerate all open Explorer windows [here](http://omegacoder.com/?p=63) but it requires C#, but perhaps [this script](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/09/15/how-can-i-tell-if-any-internet-explorer-windows-are-open-to-a-particular-web-site.aspx) will pick up Explorer windows as well.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in either batch or VBScript, at least not without an external command or COM object that "does the right thing".

Comment: what is your use case? batch is for automation. if you want to close a window, just click